# How to count number of orders for each individual user?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to MySQL and trying to select the total number of orders for each user in the orders table. Also, I'm trying to order the results by most orders to the least orders.

This is what I have for order table

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

And this is what I have for user table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(255),
  last_name VARCHAR(255),
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

I have referenced other resources and tried the following, but I'm getting an error..Not sure how I can go about it?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS user_id
FROM `order`
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: what is the error ? i guess its related to order_id, because in the table order you dont have an order_id column.

Comment: Do you want users with no orders included in the results?

Comment: Yes please I want users with number of orders each have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will

- group by user_id
- then count all lines

you will get one line per user_id with the count

ps: distinct is useless because order.id is an autoincrement key.

```
select user_id, count(*) as nb
from order
group by user_id
```

Or this if you want users with no orders included.
you need to start from user table, join all related orders, and basically do the same counting and grouping as before.

```
select u.id, count(*) as nb
from user as u
left join `order` as o on o.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
```

Comment: May I ask you what 'nb' stand for?

Comment: is just an alias to ease reading (its optional). nb for number. it could be anything. i like it because it can be used to order results for exemple. to do so you can add "order by nb desc"

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, is there any way I can order it by the most order to the least order?

Comment: did you try adding this in the end ? "order by nb desc". Or do you mean sorting by order.id ? then no you can't. it makes no sens to me.